# Simple proof of $D_t D_s V-D_sD_t V=R(\partial s, \partial t)V$? R is the curvature operator

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

On the book "Riemanian manifold" by Do Carmo, page  98.

Let $f:A \subset R^2 \to M$ be a parametrized surface and let $(s,t)$ be the usual coordinates of $R^2$. Let $V=V(s,t)$ be a vector field along $f$. Then
$$
\frac{D}{\partial t} \frac{D}{\partial s} V-\frac{D}{\partial s}\frac{D}{\partial t}V=R(\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial t})V.
$$
Where $R$ is the curvature operator. The proof is a long calculation.

I consider that whether we can proof this equality in the following way. For $f(p)\in M$, choose a nbh $V\subset A$ of $p$, and a homeomorphism $\varphi: V \times R^{n-2} \to M$, $\varphi|_{V \times{0}}=f$. Then
$$
\frac{D}{\partial t} \frac{D}{\partial s} V=\nabla_{\partial t}\nabla_{\partial s} V;
$$

$$
\frac{D}{\partial s}\frac{D}{\partial t}V=\nabla_{\partial s}\nabla_{\partial t} V;
$$
Then
$$
\frac{D}{\partial t} \frac{D}{\partial s} V-\frac{D}{\partial s}\frac{D}{\partial t}V=\nabla_{\partial t}\nabla_{\partial s} V-\nabla_{\partial s}\nabla_{\partial t} V=-\nabla_{[\partial s, \partial t]}+R(\partial s, \partial t)V=R(\partial s, \partial t)V.
$$

Comment: Although this looks ok to me, careful with ${\partial t}$ and $\partial f / \partial_t$: the first is a vector field on $A$ while the second is a vector field on $M$, and $"\frac{D}{\partial t} = \nabla_{\partial f / \partial t}"$

Comment: @mathmetricgeometry: I don't understand your argument. Let's say $f(s,t) \equiv p$ is constant. How do you extend $f$ to a **diffeomorphism** $\varphi$? The point of this lemma is that it works for arbitrary parametrized surface $f$, not necessarily an embedding (in which case you can indeed simplify the argument by choosing slice coordinates).

Comment: This is indeed a frustrating situation, where the proof by a long calculation is essentially the same as the long calculation for the formula for the Riemann curvature in terms of derivatives of Christoffel symbols. But, as mentioned above, your proof works only if $f$ is a smooth embedding, and this formula is needed when $f$ is smooth but not necessarily an embedding. There is a fancy way to to prove it abstractly (https://www.math.nyu.edu/~yangd/papers/PullbackConnection.pdf), but I think the long calculation is the simpler proof.